# Parallel Gradle task to run concurrently

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew, gradle-eclipse

```
task abc(type: Exec){
    commandLine './text1.sh'

}

task def(Type:Exec){
    commandLine './text2.sh'
}

task ListOfTasks(dependsOn['clean']){

doFirst{

    abc.execute()
    def.execute()
}

}
```

As `doFirst` is not parallel and I wanna run this two task parallel, how can I achieve this? Is this possible in gradle?

Comment: first of all: you should not use `Task.execute()` as it's considered a bad practice, and it has been deprecated (see https://discuss.gradle.org/t/task-execute-deprecation-in-5-0/24756) . Regarding task parallel execution, see this section in Gradle documentation https://guides.gradle.org/performance/#parallel_execution  : you cannot (in current Gradle version) execute tasks in parallel if they belong to the same project:  *By using the --parallel switch, you can force Gradle to execute tasks in parallel as long as those tasks are in different projects.*